# SQL SERVER-Using records in one table as column names in another table and sorting accordingly

Tags: sql-server-2008

I need some help with an SQL server problem. Currently i have a table with country names (let's call it "countries", for exposition's sake), and a table with states or provinces (named "states"), containing a FK pointing to its correponding country. I would like to generate a new table, with columns headers being the name of each of the records in "countries" in , and the content of each column being the states belonging to that specific country. It should outpout something like this:

```html
<table><tbody><tr><th>Country 1</th><th>Country 2</th><th>Country 3</th></tr><tr><td>State 1 From Country 1</td><td>State 1 From Country 2</td><td>State 1 From Country 3</td></tr><tr><td>State 2 From Country 1</td><td>State 2 From Country 2</td><td>State 2 From Country 3</td></tr><tr><td>State 3 From Country 1</td><td>State 3 From Country 2</td><td>State 3 From Country 3</td></tr><tr><td>State 4 From Country 1</td><td> </td><td>State 4 From Country 3</td></tr><tr><td>State 5 From Country 1</td><td> </td><td>State 5 From Country 3</td></tr><tr><td>State 6 From Country 1</td><td> </td><td> </td></tr><tr><td>State 7 From Country 1</td><td> </td><td> </td></tr><tr><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td></tr></tbody></table>
```

I know i can do this with PIVOT, but the problem is i have around 150 countries, and it would be pointless to type in the name of each column individually. Hope you can help me.

Comment: Why do you want to create a table like this?  It's a pretty bad idea, since the column-set will change from time to time.  If you need this for a report or just output, then what you want is merely a query (best handled by a dynamic pivot in a stored procedure), but putting it in a table implies that you intend to maintain the table data, which is a bad idea because this is a non-relational design.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Actually i need a query able to output these results. It's not like i'm intending to create and store that table. The results of those queries will be used in an excel sheet to create name ranges